# Making descendants of generic form visible and editable in VS designer

Tags: windows, forms, generics, inheritance, designer

I'm trying to create a base form using generics, so I could do sth like this:

```
public class GenericForm<T> : Form where T : IEntity
```

And then:

```
public class ManageCustomerForm : GenericForm<Customer>
```

But I'm not able to view ManageCustomerForm's designer. I understand it's because VS attempts to create an instance of GenericForm but doesn't know what type to use on T.

So I tried some solutions using TypeDescriptionProviders, cause it works for the case in which the base form class is abstract. But it doesn't work either. Is it possible?

One detail is I'd like to avoid to create an intermediate class like this:

```
public class GenericForm<T> : Form where T : IEntity

public class ManageCustomerIntermediateForm : GenericForm<Customer>

public class ManageCustomerForm : ManageCustomerIntermediateForm
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that Customer is data for the form. Instead of binding the data to the form, use a separate data class for the Customer. DataBinding can be used to tie the user interface controls to the data source.

Another idea is to use the Model-View-Controller design pattern to separate the form (the view) from the model (the customer).